# Set empty value on number column using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to assign "Column A" value to "Column B" in another list. Both columns are of "Number" data type.

When nothing is entered in Column A, Column is getting set as "0". How can I show empty in Column B also.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a condition before assigning "Column A" value to "Column B".
when "Column A" is not empty,assign "Column A" value to "Column B". Therefore, when "Column A" is empty, we do not need do anything.